# Language validation for non-English spoken users

Tags: feature-request, languages

Due SO's broad impact in the network, I believe it would be very interesting to have the following feature:

1. When a new user gets registered in any of the pages of Stack Overflow and accept the conditions of the service, he/she could select a field to specifically indicate the mastering of English language.
2. If the field is not selected, his/her posts will fall into a grammar/spelling review queue before being published.
3. Users that contribute in the correction of these questions can obtain badges and reputation.

The fact is that most of the users are willing to answer questions, but sometimes is a bit time consuming to try to understand what is the actual point, if the grammar/spelling is too bad. However, sometimes the underlying question might turn to be interesting, after all.

Comment: There are already spelling checkers built-in in browsers, so it would be better to concentrate on improving them instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. But still I'm fixing a dozen of entries every day, so it's obvious that something is not working. So, if we cannot change this fact, why shouldn't we accept a valid alternative flow, that will end up improving the overall quality of both Questions and Answers?

Comment: Related to this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202969/how-can-we-encourage-reviewers-to-care-about-spelling

Comment: Please explain downvote... And @Bart, it's not a duplicate. It might be related to, but if you read it carefully, I'm suggesting a **different** approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Not my downvote. And given that it's a feature request, it might be simple disagreement. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: Heh... I didn't mean that (probably I should open two comments instead of one to avoid this misunderstanding... ). However, a disagreement could provide some feedback as well.

Comment: And I think the duplicate is fine. The other question suggests that users can flag their own question for review. Whether or not you implement it as a flag, or a setting upon registration, the idea is pretty much the same. Unless I miss some subtlety here.

Comment: What about native speakers whose English is simply broken?

Comment: @ŁukaszL. This may be a dumb question, but if you have your locale set to something other than English, do spellcheckers use an English dictionary when you are on a English site?

Comment: @MPD it's a global setting for browser :D at least I haven't found something more configurable