# How can we encourage reviewers to care about spelling?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, spelling

This question is prompted by this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3213561

The original question title was:

> cant catch access violtation

The suggestion was to change this to:

> Can't catch access violation

I accepted the suggested edit, but the other three reviewers all decided to reject on the grounds that suggested edit was too minor.

I personally find this disappointing on multiple grounds:

1. I think spelling and appearance matter. We surely want good questions on Stack Exchange and question titles with no regard for capitalization and basic spelling should not be welcome.
2. The rejection of an edit like this will discourage the suggestor from making future edits. Which, in my opinion, will lead to the overall quality of the site's questions being poorer.

I think everyone can agree that the question would be improved by the suggested edit. Is there anything that can be done to make it more likely that such edits get accepted?

Comment: It may have been rejected not because the changes weren't important, but that there were several other problems left in the post

Comment: What about "it was rejected as too minor because there was more to fix"?

Comment: @RichardTingle The sad thing is that a reviewer should have stepped in and edited the additional problems.

Comment: @bluefeet Usually, by the time you have edited the post, the robo-reviewers have already approved it.

Comment: *"Is there anything that can be done to make it more likely that such edits get accepted?"* ... sure. Emphasize that editors should focus on the post in its entirety. I know what you're getting at, and I think I would have chosen to improve instead of reject, but ultimately it's the suggester who has to do a better job.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I know, that is part of the frustration with edit reviews.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate); [Change the wording on the “too minor” suggested edit reject message to indicate that most errors must be corrected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199342/change-the-wording-on-the-too-minor-suggested-edit-reject-message-to-indicate)

Comment: Also, I noticed you @ed the attempted editor, I don't believe a failed editor can be replied to, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198977/allow-failed-editors-be-replied-to

Comment: @RichardTingle He may not get notified, and I expected that, but if he comes back then he will notice the comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The edit makes a noticeable improvement to the post in the form of a spelling correction to the title, had the post been otherwise perfect they might have (and I would have) accepted the edit. This post however had many issues remaining

1. Strange use of commas, " , " with a space on both sides
2. "Thank you for any help."
3. :D
4. Good day.

That I could find without even reading it.

In their position I would have taken this as an attempt to just gain rep by doing the minimum work. I would certainly have rejected (and then done a good job of editing/used "improve" if I was so inclined)

Comment: Just wondering if all your spelling errors were intentional in this answer?

Comment: @JohnnyBones I was just giving someone an opportunity to gain 2 rep by fixing the 2 spelling errors in what is clearly an otherwise perfect post ;P

Comment: Hi there. Sorry but I did not notice any suggestions or anything related to the post, till this link was provided to me. From my editor I also did not notice anything. I just posted as I normally type e-mails. Will try and be more correct next time. thank you.

Comment: @Johannes I wouldn't worry too much, your question is better than 95% of most peoples first attempts.

Comment: @Richard Tingle - Thank you , appreciate it.

Comment: @RichardTingle - I had a feeling that was the case.  ;o)